# Can a pronoun represent a noun first appearing in a relative clause or first appearing as an object?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I have a question about the use of pronouns.

Can a pronoun represent a noun first appearing in a relative clause?

Can a pronoun represent a noun first appearing as an object (like the object of a verb or preposition, etc)?

Or a pronoun can always represent a noun wherever the noun first appears as long as it precede the pronoun?

Example 1:

> Friend: Why do you support the movement?
>
> Me: The movement can alleviate the problem [**which women have**] for **them**.

The bold part "which women have" is the relative clause.

Can the "them" represent the word "women", which is in the adjective clause?

Is it grammatically correct to use a pronoun like that?

Example 2:

> (1) I will come back from the store with **potatoes** in my basket and get rid of **them** for cash afterward.
>
> (2) I will amass **potatoes** and get rid of **them** for cash afterward.

Can the "them" represent the word "potatoes"?

Comment: ***When they arrested him**, John was wearing a tuxedo*. That's ***two*** pronouns in the relative clause, and nobody is likely to care much if ***they*** are never explicitly referenced by preceding or following text.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that a pronoun can be in different places. However, why does my example 1 sound awkward? Is it because it breaks grammar rules? or the "for them" is grammatically correct but just kind of redundant?

Comment: I don't understand your first example *at all*. Why would you *want* to (ungrammatically) append the relative clause ***for them*** in the first place? Sounds a bit like [Anne Elk's Theory on Brontosauruses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_Elk%27s_Theory_on_Brontosauruses) - which from memory (and it is 50 years ago now! :) she introduced by saying *This is my theory, which I have, and which is mine.* Damned good theory it was though! All the evidence so far indicates that she was absolutely right!

Comment: I mean the first example can be simply rewritten as "The movement can alleviate the problem which women have." But I want to know whether it is correct to say "The movement can alleviate the problem which women have for them(representing the women)." On the other hand, I am curious why It sounds awkward. Is it because the pronoun cannot represent a noun first appearing in an adjective sentence, or because the use of "for them" in this case is kind of redundant? By the way, can a pronoun always represent a noun wherever the noun first appears?

Comment: Okay, I'll ***give you*** an answer ***for you***. It's not *just* "redundant" - it's ***non-idiomatically redundant***. In many other contexts there's nothing at all "undesirable" about including redundant elements, but in your "women's problem" example it's simply unacceptable. But I don't think this is anything to do with pronouns. It's just the same problem with *[something which] can alleviate the problem which women have **for women***. But, syntactically speaking there's nothing particularly odd about a solution *which can alleviate **for women** the problem which **they have***.

Comment: So what you mean is that a pronoun can represent a noun wherever the noun is as long as the context is understandable for the listener, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109328/discussion-between-vincentlin-and-fumblefingers-reinstate-monica).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example 1:

Antecedeing back to the relative pronoun it only works when a *-self* pronoun is used.

> The movement can alleviate the problem which women have for *themselves*.
>
> Laura didn't want to talk about the money which was itself already spent.  (itself="the money").
>
> I'm going to take the weapon away which he's trying to hurt himself with.  (itself=whoever *he* is after which).

Exmple 2:

Yes, you can do this.  This is normal pronoun usage.  If there is ambiguity then you might not want to use a pronoun, but whether it is or not depends on context and how well the speaker/writer believes the listener/reader is engaged.

Comment: Two little questions: (1) The use of pronouns doesn't have anything to do with grammar structures like being a relative clause, being a subject or object, etc, right? (2) A pronoun can always refer to a noun wherever the noun first appears as long as the context is understandable to the listener? Sorry if this reply sounds repetitive to you, but I am trying to ensure I get a correct understanding of what you said.

Comment: @vincentin: In your comment, you're re-asking a question which has already been answered by the answer above. You ask: "A pronoun can always refer to a noun whenever the noun appears first ..."  No. If the noun is the subject of the sentence, you sometimes have to use the pronoun *myself, himself, herself, itself,* etc. For example, if you say *Mary made a necklace for her*, the pronoun *her* cannot refer to Mary. If you want to refer to Mary, you have to say "Mary made a necklace for *herself*".

Comment: And to answer your first question, whether you use *her* or *herself* does depend on grammar structures. For example, we say *She realized that they wouldn't cook for **her***, but *She realized that she would have to cook for **herself***.